# Why I can't add header to interceptor requeset OkHttp on Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, interceptor

Could you please point me my wrong in code, I couldn't add header "Authorization" to the interceptor. When I make a request it throws error **retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized** . But when I add Header token for each request

```
@Header("Authorization") String token
```

Then it works.

Here is my code:

```
 protected Retrofit retrofit;
protected OkHttpClient client;
protected T api;
protected UserCredential userCredential;

public RestClient(Class<T> type) {
    if (client == null) {
        synchronized (OkHttpClient.class) {
            client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.newBuilder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request original = chain.request();
                Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder();
                if (GrabDoiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentCredentials() != null) {
                    String token = GrabDoiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentCredentials().getToken();
                    if (token != null) {
                        builder.addHeader("Authorization", token);
                    }
                }
                builder.method(original.method(), original.body());

                return chain.proceed(builder.build());
            }).build();

            if (retrofit == null) {
                synchronized (Retrofit.class) {
                    Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(Constants.GRABDOI_SERVER_URL)
                            .client(client)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create());
                    retrofit = retrofitBuilder.build();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    api = retrofit.create(type);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put the access to the static method out of the interceptor's body:

```
    public RestClient(Class<T> type) {
    if (retrofit != null) {
        return;
    }
    synchronized (OkHttpClient.class) {
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = client.newBuilder();
        final String token;
        if (GrabDoiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentCredentials() != null &&
                (token = GrabDoiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentCredentials().getToken()) != null) {
            builder.addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                builder.addHeader("Authorization", token);
                builder.method(original.method(), original.body());
                return chain.proceed(builder.build());
            });
        }
        client = builder.build();

        synchronized (Retrofit.class) {
            Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.GRABDOI_SERVER_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create());
            retrofit = retrofitBuilder.build();
        }
    }


    api = retrofit.create(type);
}
```